# How nuget install decides when to download a new version of a package?

Tags: windows, nuget

My scenario is this:

1. Use nuget install without version to get the latest version of a package
2. Publish a new version of the package
3. Check with nuget list that the new version is indeed published
4. Run nuget install again.

What I noticed is that nuget install does not fetch the new version right away. It takes about an hour to see it.

So how does it work exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget caches all made requests in the http-cache (see "nuget locals" in the docs for reference). Objects (aka queries and their result) in this cache have an expiration of about 30minutes to 1 hour depending on the version of nuget.exe.

Use `nuget locals http-cache -clear` to clear this cache, then nuget should fetch the new versions without having to wait

Comment: Do you know if this is configurable?

Comment: i'm afraid this is not configurable